# Dont see source code in Eclipse Debug

Tags: eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I configurate Eclipse Kepler like in this tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Running_and_debugging_your_executables_within_Eclipse

When I try debug code, I see only disassembled code.
Can I see c++ source code of my project?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108206/dont-see-source-code-in-eclipse-debug/) by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2013-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to compile your package with debug symbols.

```
catkin_make --pkg <package_name> --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

Or for all packages:

```
catkin_make --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2014-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zacryon](https://answers.ros.org/users/40560/zacryon/) on 2019-03-21**:
Thanks a lot! I had the same problem with Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0) and ROS Kinetic under Ubuntu 16.04. I did, what the wiki page demanded (using the catkin-y approach) which helped to run and build the package from within eclipse, but debugging wasn't working. Got "No source available for main()" as error. Your suggestion solved my problem.